# display a particular string if a string variable is empty in php

Tags: php

I have a php class as shown below:

```
<?php

class helloWorld
{
    public $ab;
    public $cd;
    public $ef;
    public $gh;
    public $ij;
    public $kl;

    public function __construct($ab = 0,
                                    $cd = 0,
                                    $ef = 0,
                                    $gh = 0,
                                    $ij = '',
                                    $kl = '')
    {
        $this->ab = $ab;
        $this->cd = $cd;
        $this->ef = $ef;
        $this->gh = $gh;
        $this->ij = $ij;
        $this->kl = $kl;
    }
}
```

**Problem Statement:** What I want to achieve is if `$kl` is empty then assign `ZZ` to `$kl`.

This is what I have tried. Let me know if it looks good or if there are any changes I need to make.

```
<?php

class helloWorld
{
    public $ab;
    public $cd;
    public $ef;
    public $gh;
    public $ij;
    public $kl;

    public function __construct($ab = 0,
                                    $cd = 0,
                                    $ef = 0,
                                    $gh = 0,
                                    $ij = '',
                                    $kl = '')
    {
        $this->ab = $ab;
        $this->cd = $cd;
        $this->ef = $ef;
        $this->gh = $gh;
        $this->ij = $ij;
        if ('' == $kl || is_null($kl)) {    
            $kl = 'ZZ';
        }
        $this->kl = $kl;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Does your code _not_ work? What is your question?

Comment: @Phil I have updated my question. Let me know if I am clear now.

Comment: **Does your code not work?** StackOverflow is not a code-review service

Answer (score 1):

your code is correct but it shout be short

```
 <?php

class helloWorld
{
    public $ab;
    public $cd;
    public $ef;
    public $gh;
    public $ij;
    public $kl;

    public function __construct($ab = 0,
                                    $cd = 0,
                                    $ef = 0,
                                    $gh = 0,
                                    $ij = '',
                                    $kl = '')
    {
        $this->ab = $ab;
        $this->cd = $cd;
        $this->ef = $ef;
        $this->gh = $gh;
        $this->ij = $ij;
        $this->kl = empty($kl) ? 'ZZ' : $kl;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: OP says they want `ZZ` (all capitals). I'd just use `$this->kl = empty($kl) ? 'ZZ' : $kl;`

Comment: @Phil yes you are right, edited